# SQL Server - Trouble passing variable to a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I know this is a basic question - but I can't figure the correct way to get this done.

I need to pass a variable to a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure and return the query.

Here's the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pOrders
AS
    DECLARE @enteredClientID varchar(20);
    DECLARE @Results table (ClientID varchar(20), Num_orders int);
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Get all the order from the client
    INSERT INTO @Results
      SELECT ClientID, sum(Num_orders)
      FROM Orders O
      WHERE O.ClientID = @enteredClientID
      GROUP BY O.ClientID);

    -- Insert the orders into the results table --
    SELECT *
    FROM @Results;

END
GO;
```

Now, I would execute the stored procedure and get the result back:

```
exec pOrders
set @enteredClientID = 'ABC123456789'
```

I get this error message back:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@enteredClientID".

But, I'm declaring the variable....  what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't declare a parameter, but a local variable. To declare it as you wanted to:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pOrders (@enteredClientID varchar(20))
AS
    DECLARE @Results table (ClientID varchar(20), Num_orders int);

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Get all the order from the client
    INSERT INTO @Results
    SELECT ClientID, sum(Num_orders)
    FROM Orders O
    WHERE O.ClientID = @enteredClientID
    GROUP BY O.ClientID);

    -- Insert the orders into the results table --
    SELECT *
    FROM @Results;

GO;
```

An to call it:

```
exec pOrders @enteredClientID = 'ABC123456789'
```

or simply

```
exec pOrders 'ABC123456789'
```

Answer (score 1):

--In stored proc

```
DECLARE @enteredClientID varchar(20) OUTPUT
```

--Then insert and set identity

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS @enteredClientID
```

--When calling procedure:
-- DECLARE variables to hold the return value

```
DECLARE @enteredClientID VARCHAR(20);
```

-- Execute the procedure, which returns value.

```
EXEC @enteredClientID = pOrders
```

Answer (score 0):

Try EXEC pOrders 'ABC123456789'.

The call you provided attempts to execute the procedure (with no parameters passed), then attempts to set a variable named @enteredClientID.  Since you have not declared @enteredClientID in the scope of the executing code, it cannot set it.

For more information about how to use parameters with procedures, this article may be helpful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189915.aspx

Comment: Just a suggestion: it may make sense to use a table-valued function instead of a procedure to meet this need...but that's outside of the scope of the question :-)