# MySQL to output only n number of rows and group the rest into n+1 th row

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, aggregate-functions

Is it possible to build a SQL query to output only n number of rows and sum up the rest of the columns returned n+1 th row.

for instance, I have two columns returned from an sql query. First column is the Name and the second column contains the count values. The names are distinct and the counts are numbers.

The query should only return 3 rows and if there are more than 3 rows, they all should be summed up to a fourth row with the name as 'Others' and the counts of the rest of the rows summed up into the fourth row.

Kindly help me out. Thanks in advance.

(example) 
**Table**
Name | Value
First - 12
Second - 11
Third - 9
Fourth - 15
Fifth - 13
Sixth - 8

**Query result**
Name | Value 
First - 12
Second - 11
Third - 9
Others - 36

Comment: Any existing research on attempt for it?

Comment: Is there a reason it _has_ to be one 1 query? I can be done, but its a bit kludgy for something that is basically very simple in 2 queries.

Comment: anything is fine. Two queries with temp tables will also do. I just wanted a rough idea how it can be achieved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would look like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 Col1, Col2
FROM Table
```

Unless you were wanting to have the second column a count of things, then it would be

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 Col1, Count(Col2) AS "New Name"
FROM Table
GROUP BY Col1
```

This is under the assumption you ONLY want the top 3.  If you do want a 4th row, do a UNION with another select statement that uses OFFSET, that way you can select all rows but the top 3.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032803/select-all-rows-except-top-row), [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx), and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) for examples on TOP, OFFSET, and UNION.

Re-reading the first part of your question, if you are looking to have the TOP number change, you will most likely need to have it as a stored procedure with a variable passed that controls the number for the TOP and OFFSET. Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660063/sql-server-trouble-passing-variable-to-a-stored-procedure) as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try `GROUP BY...WITH ROLLUP` to sum all the rows count in n+1 row. Try below example.

```
SELECT IFNULL(a.id, 'Other'), SUM(1) ids
FROM tableA 
GROUP BY a.id WITH ROLLUP
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Could you try something like this :

select case(name) 
    when 'First' THEN 'First'
    when 'Second' THEN 'Second'
    when 'Third' THEN 'Third'
    else 'Others'
end name, sum(value) value
from table
group by case(name) 
    when 'First' THEN 'First'
    when 'Second' THEN 'Second'
    when 'Third' THEN 'Third'
    else 'Others'
```